# How can I tell VS Code that I'm editing CSS?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

So I'm new to VS Code... loved it from a preview in a Python tutorial.

I open it and start entering some CSS code I'm working on, yet the editor does not:

1. Make suggestions or corrections;
2. Highlight key words;
3. Seem to care or know that I'm editing a specific language (i.e.: CSS).

How do I tell it that's the language I want it to use?

Comment: have u saved the file using .css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating new files you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> then <kbd>m</kbd> or just click the language mode link in the bottom right of VS Code to specify CSS. That should trigger the autocomplete/suggest/syntax highlighting features. By default VS Code will look at the file extension when opening existing files to determine which language to select.

See https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/overview for more info.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for.  The editor is a splendid addition to what I'm already using, but I got it specifically to use for offbeat projects like the CSS project I'm working on now.  Thanks bunches.